# Check if textBox contains this specific character configuration

Tags: c#

I have a textbox with a long string of characters, and I need to check if a combination of 9 characters and numbers separated by hyphens exists (such as FSX-TVD-D5M). If that's found, copy only that bit of the string to another textBox.

I've looked at regex methods to accomplish this but haven't quite figured out a working method. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{3}/g
```

Please try like above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I put: if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"/\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{3}/g"))

            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
            }
but nothing happens. Is something wrong?

Comment: Just `@"\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{3}"` in C#